# include record where split happened

Tags: java

I have records in a file like given below

```
21
22
23
17
11
13
17
21
22
23
21
22
23
17
19
```

I want to split this file into multiple file on every 17. But whenever I split on 17, this record is shifting to new file. But what I need is, the record on which I'm splitting should stay in previous file not next or new file.

I've tried this in my tool

```
output_row.line = input_row.line;



if (input_row.line.equals("17")) {

    globalMap.put("value", input_row.line+"_"+Numeric.sequence("s", 1, 1));

}
```

Then I'm using globalMap.get("record") in my output path of files. For dynamic split

I want my splitted files like these.

```
file:1
21
22
23
17

file:2
11
13
17

file:3
21
22
23
21
22
23
17

file:4
19
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Q: So what do your actual file1, file2, ...look like?

Comment: @paulsm4...Thanks for the response...I figured out the solution